# If a written line of poetry ends ᴡɪᴛʜᴏᴜᴛ a punctuation mark and the next line starts with “and”, is this considered an enjambment?

Tags: terminology, punctuation, poetry, poetic-devices

In the poem [“Planetarium” by Adrienne Rich](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/46568/planetarium-56d2267df376c),
there are the following lines:

> of a woman trying to translate pulsations
> into images   for the relief of the body
> and the reconstruction of the mind.

The questions asks: (*for the relief.... of the mind*) is the poetic device used here enjambment or alliteration?

The answer is Alliteration, but I don’t understand why exactly it’s not Enjambment though.

Comment: For an ‘or’ question only one can be right so you also have to be able to say definitively that it is not alliteration (and you can’t)

Comment: @Jim, that were to assume that the authors of dual- or multiple-choice test questions have some clue what they are asking about. Top scorers know it is often advantageous to dumb oneself down a little so as to meet the test authors at their own level. Both enjambment and alliteration are in play in these lines.

Comment: The definition of "enjambment" is a bit fuzzy and not always absolutely clear cut. You don't have the two options of decisive break and obvious running-over, but sometimes something in between. Often you'll identify it because there's a bigger pause in the middle of the line than at the end, or because it stands out compared to the rest of a poem.

Comment: I'd say claiming alliteration after the first line is pushing it. Though as Stuart says, enjambment can depend on the school of the definer.

Comment: This is hard to answer because it’s unclear how “everybody”—let alone the maker of your exercise—deﬁnes **enjambment**. Sure, if the end-of-line (␊) is also the end of a clause, that’s an easy call that it’s **end-stopped**. But here it’s `"for NP₁ ␊ and NP₂"` where neither NP spans the line-break indicated there by ␊; but the prepositional phrase `"for X"` where X = `"NP₁ and NP₂"` certainly does so. Perhaps it boils down to whether a line-break within *any* syntactic constituent counts as enjambment, or whether clause boundaries alone are all one cares about for this determination.